# Installer for Windows Server 2008R2 blue screens under Hyper-V 2012

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, hyper-v, hyper-v-server-2012, bsod

Trying to build an SQL Server cluster lab on an old Dell Latitude E6400 with 6gb RAM, using Hyper-V 2012.  The install works great, I can create VMs and networks just fine, but when I try to boot the 2008 R2 install ISO, it blue screens like the screenie below.

[image: BSOD in 2008r2 install]

On occasion the first number in the brackets is 0xc000012d.

It loads files off the ISO, displays the "Starting Windows" screen without animation, goes to the Vista loading bar before displaying that message.

I've run up every update that was available and even tried turning on the old OS option under Processor, to no avail.  The same happens with or without SP1 in the 2008R2 ISO.

Any pointers or cluesticks will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: is it possibly for x64?

Comment: Check your ISO image. It is probably corrupt. Or you have bad hardware. It is a five year old laptop, after all...

Comment: @Fergus, 2008R2 is 64-bit only, and the host is also 64-bit.

Comment: @MichaelHampton, wouldn't the guest be suffering issues as well, if the hardware was suspect?  I just unpacked both ISOs using 7zip and it assured me that everything was OK on each occasion.

Comment: It looks to me like the guest _is_ suffering issues!

Comment: @MichaelHampton If the _host_ is suffering issues.  Sorry, caffeine hadn't kicked in yet.

Comment: ****SAN1 is not your guest?

Comment: @MichaelHampton It is, but it's not the only one.  The exact same thing happens with the DC.  I've just realised what's going on, I'll answer my own question with the cause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem - the SQL servers booted just fine, and the reason was that, while dynamic memory was turned on, the lower bound was set at 256mb, which, it turns out, is not enough memory to load the boot.wim file into memory.  As soon as I raised the minimum to 512mb, it was fine.